# How to stop my washing machine from squeaking?

Tags: appliances, washing-machine, noise, squeak

I own a GE WHDSR316G2WW washing machine. It was whisper-silent when new, but after a few years and several off-balance loads, it developed a persistent squeak that seemed to happen mostly when the motor would change direction while agitating a load.

Yesterday I finally got around to changing the drive belt, and that helped a bit, but the squeak's still there. While I had the machine apart, though, I found the source of the squeak. There are two metal tabs that, when the tub is filled with water and riding low, rub against the inside bottom of the washer shell:

[image]

Here's a wider view for context:

[image]

I'm not sure about the purpose of these tabs, nor why they didn't squeak when the washer was new, but do now. In any case, I can think of a few possible quick fixes:

- Grease the points of contact between these tabs and the washer shell. This might work for a while, but there's no evidence of grease there now, so I doubt this was the original solution. It probably wouldn't take much time for the grease to be rubbed away, either.
- Use cable ties (or similar) to fasten the tabs to the nearby brackets. This could prevent them from getting close enough to the bottom shell to make contact, but it would also restrict the tub's range of motion, which is probably a bad idea (e.g., I could see that worsening vibration).
- Bend/shave the brackets to increase clearance. This could work, but it seems like they're meant to be the length they are now to prevent other parts of the tub assembly (like the motor and ballast) from bottoming out.

Is there a proper way to handle this - maybe just another common maintenance chore that I'm missing? Can I tune up or adjust the tub's suspension to be firmer and thus ride higher to avoid bottoming out on these tabs? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

congratulations on your choice of machine - it was sold by sears, even if you did not buy it there, they have parts, unless you find them somewhere else on line.

So, i visited

http://www.searspartsdirect.com/GE-Washer-Parts/Model-WHDSR316G2WW/0432/0153200.html

On to this page

http://www.searspartsdirect.com/ge-washer-parts/model-WHDSR316G2WW/0432/0153200/G0803213/00004.html

We see part 414 Rod and suppression spring assembly part  WH16X544

This is a mfg substitute part which to me has always said 'we found the problem after we sold that one to you - now buy this part to fix it right'

RepairClinic, my favored appliance parts place - this week has the part for $23.40
http://www.repairclinic.com/PartDetail/Suspension-Rod/WH16X544/278886

Sears has it for $25.23
http://www.searspartsdirect.com/ge-washer-parts/WH16X0544/0026/363/model-WHDSR316G2WW/0432/0153200.html

Since the entire motor assembly is supported by those springs, and the weaker the springs get, the closer they get to scraping the motor mount on the bottom of the washer pan.

I think you replace those and it will have its spring back in its spin cycle